# Embedded Outlook 365 Calendar auto-scrolls to the calendar section after page fully loads

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, calendar, embed

There is something in the calendar that forces it to autos-croll to the section of the page where the calendar is embedded. How do I prevent this from happening? Is there something that can be added into iframe, or css? Or maybe there is a simple javascript solution?

Any ideas appreciated.

```
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/18c7a310a7a542c0863b9c2fa1c19bdf/calendar.html" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `style="display: none;" onload="this.style.display='block';"` to iframe fixed the problem.

```
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe style="display: none;" onload="this.style.display='block';" src="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/18c7a310a7a542c0863b9c2fa1c19bdf/calendar.html" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```